# Convert date number to words using java

Tags: java

I want to convert a date to words. For example: `12/12/2012` --> `twelve twelve two thousand twelve` and I already made number to word converter. But now I have problem to print it out.

Here my code:

```
   String patternString = "\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}"; // date regex

   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString); // pattern compiling
   Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(nom); // matching with pattern with input text from user

   if (matcher.find()) {
       String get_data = matcher.group();
           if(get_data.contains("/")){ // check either has "/" slash or not
              String parts[] = get_data.split("[/]"); // split process
              String get_day = parts[0]; // day will store in first array
              String get_month = parts[1]; // month will store in second array
              String get_year = parts[2]; // year will store in third array

              String s = NumberConvert.convert(Integer.parseInt(get_day)) 
                        + NumberConvert.convert(Integer.parseInt(get_month)) 
                        + NumberConvert.convert(Integer.parseInt(get_year));
              String replace = matcher.replaceAll(s); // replace number to words
              System.out.println(replace);
            }
   } else {...}
```

Input text from user:

```
12/12/2012 +++ 23/11/2010
```

But the result print only first pattern and next pattern also replace with value of first pattern too.

```
twelve twelve two thousand twelve +++ twelve twelve two thousand twelve
```

Please suggest me the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An immediate solution to your problem would be to use `Matcher.replaceFirst()`, instead of `Matcher.replaceAll()`, since you only want the *first* date pattern to be replaced with your written version of the date.

```
String replace = matcher.replaceFirst(s);
```

If you would like to be able to process each numeric date one at a time, you can do so in a left-to-right fashion using this code:

```
String patternString = "\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(nom);

String output = "";

while (matcher.find()) {
    String get_data = matcher.group();

    String parts[] = get_data.split("/");
    String get_day = parts[0];
    String get_month = parts[1];
    String get_year = parts[2];

    String s = NumberConvert.convert(Integer.parseInt(get_day)) +
               NumberConvert.convert(Integer.parseInt(get_month)) +
               NumberConvert.convert(Integer.parseInt(get_year));

    if (output.equals("")) {
        output = s;
    }
    else {
        output += " +++ " + s;
    }

    String replace = matcher.replaceFirst("");
    matcher = pattern.matcher(replace);
}
```

After each iteration, the above code resets the `Matcher` using a string from which the previous date matched has been removed.  This lets you "eat" one date at a time, from left to right, building the human readable date output as you go along.

Comment: Thanks but I would like to convert all date pattern with different value. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Could I print the last iteration only?

Comment: Yes, this is easy.  Just print whatever the value of `s` is after the loop finishes.  Keep in mind you will have to define `String s` outside the loop if you want it to work.

Comment: Thanks @ Tim Biegeleisen